How do I create a CHECK constraint for this attribute?
The student details include name, roll number, address, university email id and mobile number.
The format of the roll number is department name in two letters (CS for Computer Science and Engineering, AM for AI and Machine Learning), one letter for the course (M for MS and P for PhD) and a two digit roll number starting with 01.
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
ROLL_NO CHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY CHECK(ROLL_NO LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][M,P][0-9][0-9][01-99]'),
NAME VARCHAR(20),
ADDR VARCHAR(50),
SMOB_NO BIGINT CHECK (MOB_NO BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 9999999999),
SU_EMAIL VARCHAR(20)
);

Error message:

Runtime error near line 13: CHECK constraint failed: ROLL_NO LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][M,P][0-9][0-9][0-9]' (19)


your database may not be recognising [01-99] as a valid range; how is it meant to be interpreted?

LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][M,P][0-9][0-9][01-99]' appears to be an attempt to use regex type processing which would require a regexp user function, which by default isn't defined.

there are SQLite implementations that incorporate/define/come with  a regexp function in which case you could utilise REGEXP instead of LIKE (the latter limited to use of % (wild characters) and _ (1 wild character))

It would appear that you want something along the lines of:-
....
CHECK (
    substr(roll_no,1,2) BETWEEN 'AA' AND 'zz' /*any 2 letter department */
    AND substr(roll_no,3,1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'z' /* any single letter course */
    AND substr(roll_no,4,2) BETWEEN '01' AND '99' /* any two numerics BUT NOT 00, so 01 or greater */
    ),
....

If you wanted more specific departments e.g. just AM and CS and more specific courses e.g. just M or P then the above could instead be:-
....
CHECK (
    substr(roll_no,1,2) IN ('AM','CS')
    AND substr(roll_no,3,1) IN ('M','P')
    AND substr(roll_no,4,2) BETWEEN '01' AND '99'
    ),
....


i.e. IN with a comma separated list of valid values instead of BETWEEN the lowest and highest acceptable values (thus allowing any intermediate values)

The following demonstrates both usages:-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STUDENT (
ROLL_NO CHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY 
    CHECK (
        substr(roll_no,1,2) BETWEEN 'AA' AND 'zz' /*any 2 letter department */
        AND substr(roll_no,3,1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'z' /* any single letter course */
        AND substr(roll_no,4,2) BETWEEN '01' AND '99' /* any two numerics BUT NOT 00, so 01 or greater */
        ),
NAME VARCHAR(20),
ADDR VARCHAR(50),
SMOB_NO BIGINT CHECK (SMOB_NO BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 9999999999),
SU_EMAIL VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO student
    VALUES 
        ('AMA01','Fred Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('zzZ02','Barney Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('aaa03','Wilma Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('ZZz99','Betty Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx')
;
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO student
    VALUES 
        ('01AMA','Fred Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('zz102','Barney Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('0aaa3','Wilma Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('A','Betty Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx')
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS STUDENT (
ROLL_NO CHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY 

    /**/
    CHECK (
        substr(roll_no,1,2) IN ('AM','CS')
        AND substr(roll_no,3,1) IN ('M','P')
        AND substr(roll_no,4,2) BETWEEN '01' AND '99'
        ),
NAME VARCHAR(20),
ADDR VARCHAR(50),
SMOB_NO BIGINT CHECK (SMOB_NO BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 9999999999),
SU_EMAIL VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO student
    VALUES 
        ('AMP01','Fred Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('CSM02','Barney Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('AMM03','Wilma Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('CSM04','Betty Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx')
;
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO student
VALUES 
        ('01AMA','Fred Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('zz102','Barney Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('0aaa3','Wilma Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('A','Betty Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('MAP01','Fred Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('SCM02','Barney Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('AMQ03','Wilma Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('CSR04','Betty Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx')
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student;

The 4 INSERTS resulting in the outputs (the pertinent results being the number of affected rows which are how many rows were inserted as opposed to ignored):-
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO student
    VALUES 
        ('AMA01','Fred Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('zzZ02','Barney Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('aaa03','Wilma Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('ZZz99','Betty Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx')
> Affected rows: 4
> Time: 0.024s


i.e. all 4 rows have been inserted as they meet the all the criteria to not result in a conflict (CHECKs and the implied UNIQUE)

then
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO student
    VALUES 
        ('01AMA','Fred Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('zz102','Barney Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('0aaa3','Wilma Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('A','Betty Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx')
> Affected rows: 0
> Time: 0s


i.e. 0 rows have been inserted, but IGNOREd so the conflicts (ALL 4) have not halted processing.

The first row has 01 as the first 2 characters and thus fails the substr(1,2) BETWEEN 'AA' AND 'zz'
The 2nd row passes the first 2 characters but then fails the 3rd character CHECK
The 3rd row fails the first CHECK
The 4th row fails the first CHECK (and would fail the others) as it is just a single character.



then
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO student
    VALUES 
        ('AMP01','Fred Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('CSM02','Barney Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('AMM03','Wilma Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('CSM04','Betty Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx')
> Affected rows: 4
> Time: 0.024s

finally to test the IN in more detail:-
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO student
    VALUES 
        ('01AMA','Fred Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('zz102','Barney Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('0aaa3','Wilma Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('A','Betty Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('MAP01','Fred Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('SCM02','Barney Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('AMQ03','Wilma Flintstone','1 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx'),
        ('CSR04','Betty Rubble','3 Quary Avenue, Bedrock', 1919191919,'x@x.xxx')
> Affected rows: 0
> Time: 0s


The first 4 have failed the CHECK as expected. The latter 4 though use what would have been valid (first 3 characters are letters) BUT fails the more specific CHECK as only AMP, AMM, CSP or CSM are allowed for the first 3 characters.


--Create you table like below
--in oracle like operator not support while creating table
--below query will work
CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
ROLL_NO VARCHAR2(7) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(ROLL_NO, '^[A-Z][A-Z][M,P][0-9]{2}$')),
NAME VARCHAR2(20),
ADDR VARCHAR2(50),
SMOB_NO number CHECK (SMOB_NO BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 9999999999),
SU_EMAIL VARCHAR2(20)
);

Oracle? Question is about SQLite. [answer].
